# How to display all errors for a form in a grails layout?

Tags: validation, grails

I have the following code in my layout page:

```
<g:hasErrors>
    <div class="alert alert-error">Please try submitting again</div>
    <g:eachError>
        <p>${it.defaultMessage}</p>
    </g:eachError>
</g:hasErrors>
```

Basically when the form is submitted and if there are any errors then I'd like the errors to be shown.

However, the errors are being shown like this:

```
Please try submitting again
Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be blank
```

Why aren't the messages being shown properly?

This is what I have in my constraints:

```
static constraints = {
    color(nullable:  false, blank: false, size: 5..15)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling message on the error to all arguments injected.
For more customizations, see your *message.properties*.

```
<g:hasErrors>
  <div class="alert alert-error">Please try submitting again</div>
    <g:eachError>
      <p><g:message error="${it}" /></p>
    </g:eachError>
</g:hasErrors>
```